# Dynamic variable name not working

Tags: javascript

Using the code below I am trying to create dynamic variable name to use later in creating / working with Mongo db collection, yet I am getting error (undefined) shown below also collection is never created, so was wondering if someone please can tell me what I am doing wrong / missing here? Thanks

```
  var global = this;
  var collId = 'Test'; 

  console.log(collId); //return undefined...

  global[collId] = new Meteor.Collection(collId); //will create a collection with name Test but it is not accessible
```

Comment: What do you expect `this` to return?

Comment: Nobody can really answer this without knowing what `x` is...

Comment: @Anonymous problem solved, assuming I pass collId a static string. Thanks

Comment: @PM77-1 this pointing to global object

Comment: @MChan In that case I can't reproduce the `undefined` problem. If you defined `collId` in the line before, I can't imagine how it would be undefined.